# On-blur in angular directive not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have created a form. I have two email fields one is for Email and the other is confirm Email.

I wanted to create a directive which will compare confirmEmail field and Email field on blur of ConfirmEmail field. And on blur of confirm email i wanted to validate and show message if it doesn't match with email field.

Doubt: I am almost done. But somehow the onblur is not behaving properly.

One of the below case:

When I enter **a@x** in email field. Then **a@t** in confirm email field and tab out. I see the validation message as it doesn't match.

After that when I go back to confirm email field and make **a@xsdf** and tab out the validation doesn't fire.But if I type in some other textbox in the form like firstname then message gets reflected. Could you please suggest what is wrong in the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title></title>
</head>


<form name="myForm" novalidate>
  <div class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="myController">
    <br>
    <br> First Name
    <br>
    <firstname></firstname>
    <div ng-if="myForm.txtFirstName.$dirty">
      <div class="danger" ng-show="myForm.txtFirstName.$error.pattern">
        Enter First Name without Special Character
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br> Last Name
    <br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="LastName" name="txtLastName" class="form-control"></input>
    <br>
    <br> Email
    <br>
    <input type="email" name="txtemail" ng-model="Email" class="form-control"></input>
    <div ng-if="myForm.txtemail.$dirty">
      <div class="danger" ng-show="myForm.txtemail.$invalid">
        Enter Valid Email Id
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br> Confirm Email
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="txtConfirmEmail" ng-disabled="!myForm.txtemail.$viewValue"
    ng-model="EmailConfirm" match  match-Email="{{Email}}" match-Cemail="{{EmailConfirm}}" class="form-control"></input>
    <div class="danger" ng-show="mismatch">
      <span>Email and Confirm Email must match.</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
</html>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Tn70GxyqAadg0EdqjFG6?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery events doesnt trigger `$digest` circle of angular, you should use `$apply` for trigger this circle

```
    scope.mismatch = false;
    debugger
    if (attrs.matchEmail === attrs.matchCemail) {
       scope.$apply(function(){
         scope.mismatch = false
      });
    } else
       scope.$apply(function(){
         scope.mismatch = true
      });
  });
```

Comment: wow thanks, It' working as expected :) Couple of doubts : is it only with jquery events or with javascript events too($digest cycle not triggering).
Is it I always need to use $apply when dealing with jquery/javascript events.
Is $apply a heavy operation. Or is it ok to use it. If its is expensive operation, Is there any alternative solution for this in this scenario.

Comment: check [understanding-angulars-apply-digest](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)

Answer (score 0):

One way around is to replace {{Email}} with current form value:

```
<input type="text" name="txtConfirmEmail" ng-disabled="!myForm.txtemail.$viewValue"
ng-model="EmailConfirm" match  match-Email="{{myForm.txtemail.$viewValue}}" match-Cemail="{{EmailConfirm}}" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get into the habit of using the "dot" on the scope;  In your situation you should be using:

```js
$scope.model = {
    mismatch: false
  }
```

Here's your fixed plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/XEZjkXaIecGC4oBox5Z0?p=preview

Comment: Just checked the plunker. Type a@x in Email field. Then a@t in confirm email. Onblur validation is firing. Now go back to  confirmEmail Field. Type a@y. Then on blur/tabout the validation should fire.Its not happening.